# How can I aggregate by different levels pivot then inner join in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and i have a dataframe with transactional data. I would like to group by the person ID but by different attributes, e.g. shop type, and education level.

```
%%spark
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf 

df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM  df  limit 10")

shoptypes = df.select('shoptype').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()

edulevel = df.select('edulevel').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()

pivot_1 = df.groupBy("id").pivot("shoptype", shoptypes).sum("amount")
pivot_1 .show()


pivot_2 = df.groupBy("id").pivot("edulevel", edulevel).count()
pivot_2 .show()

alldfs = pivot_1.join(pivot_2, pivot_2.id == pivot_1.id, how='inner').drop(pivot_2.id)
```

alldfs is empty after i inner join. How can this be when pivot 1 and pivot 2 have same ids?

However what i find strange is that pivot_1 and pivot_2 do not show the same person IDs - i thought they would since they are created from same source? I dont know what is happening. Can anybody help? I essentially want to aggregate on different attrubytes and pivot then horizontally join on the person id. So i end up with rows as my ids and columns as pivoted attributes.

Comment: Your use and implementation of pivot is wrong. please check https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-pivot-and-unpivot-dataframe/ the link to correctly use it. Also provide sample data and expected output here.

Comment: have edited to add input.

Comment: I think in the output for id 1 tesco will have 4000 and Asos 1500. Or you are eliminating duplicating id's randomly using dropDuplicates?

Comment: I didn't consider the content, i really thought pivot was self explanatory.. :P. Removed the input and example as it is probably confusing. But pivoting a table like you would in excel/python.

Comment: Just to be sure. Your original select doesn´t have a limit right?
If you have a limit in your original select, then this is the problem since limit is not determinstic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Limit clause in a Select Statement is not deterministic. Since Spark is lazy evaluated, the SQL statement will be executed twice and you will get different ids in pivot_1 and pivot_2.

Comment: Thanks for this makes sense